# editor.BlockListBlock Filter not passing BlockListBlock to Function

Tags: wordpress, reactjs, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks, create-guten-block

When I have `define( 'SCRIPT_DEBUG', true );` In my `wp-config.php`, I receive the correct object from calling this hook: `editor.BlockListBlock`. When I have `define( 'SCRIPT_DEBUG', false );` or not defined, I receive the wrong object.

```
const { createHigherOrderComponent } = wp.compose;

const withClientIdClassName = createHigherOrderComponent( ( BlockListBlock ) => {
// BlockListBlock returns as "WithSelect" with debug off
// and returns as the correct component with debug on
    console.log(BlockListBlock);
    return ( props ) => {
    const {attributes, name} = props;
        if(name === 'project/block-name'){
            return <BlockListBlock { ...props } className={'classes-i-want-on-this'} />;
        } else {
            return <BlockListBlock { ...props } />;
        }

    };
}, 'withClientIdClassName' );

wp.hooks.addFilter( 'editor.BlockListBlock', 'classNames-for-cells', withClientIdClassName );
```

With SCRIPT_DEBUG not defined or false

[image]

With SCRIPT_DEBUG true

[image]

I used this to start up my project
https://github.com/ahmadawais/create-guten-block

Comment: `withSelect` is just a HOC wrap for your `BlockListBlock` that will add some props to the BlockListBlock. So the result is not "wrong" just wrapped. Are classes added to your block or not?

Comment: For my actual block it works. The thing that doesn't happen is modification of BlockListBlock component.